# Simultaneous solution(s) to $a^2+4b^2+4ab=0$ and $a^2+4b^2+32+16a-8b=0$?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Could you tell me just how should I solve this system:
$$
a^2+4b^2+4ab=0\\
a^2+4b^2+32+16a-8b=0
$$

I can't remember the proceeding and it's driving me crazy.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

The first equation gives $(a+2b)^2=0\Rightarrow a=-2b$. Sub in the second equation gives $b$ value.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Start by taking the difference between the two equations, to get
$$
32+16a+8b-4ab=0
$$
Or, dividing by 4,
$$
8+4a+2b-ab=0
$$
Now, turn your attention to the first equation. It can be factored.

Comment: You saved my day, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

We have: 
$$
a^2+4b^2+4ab=0 \tag{1}$$
$$
a^2+4b^2+32+16a-8b=0\tag{2}
$$

$\bf (I)$ Subtract equation $(2)$ from $(1)$:

$$\begin{align}
& a^2+4b^2+4ab & =0\\
- & a^2+4b^2+32+16a-8b &=0 \\
& \hline \\
= & 4ab -16a + 8b - 32 & = 0 \\
4 & (ab - 4a + 2b - 8) & = 0 \\ \\
= & ab - 4a + 2b -8 = 0 \tag{3}\\
\end{align}
$$

$\bf (II)$ Factor equation $(1)$ $$
a^2+4b^2+4ab=0 \iff (a + 2b)^2 = 0 \iff a = -2b \tag{4}
$$

$\bf (III)$

Substitute $a = -2b$ into equation $(3)$. Then solve for $a$ the solution for $b$ to obtain $a = -2b$.

Comment: Let me know if this helps, surfer! ;-)

Comment: I prefer to have this be mine. +

Comment: @amWhy: So beautifully formatted! +1